# SceneKit With Vuforia AR library custom models

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, scenekit, vuforia

I am new in `SceneKit`, working with `swift 3` and latest `Vuforia` library 6-2-9.

I have a problem with applying `textures` on custom 3D models.

```
fileprivate func createDefaultMarkerScene(with view: VuforiaEAGLView) -> SCNScene {
    let scene = SCNScene()

    let lightNode = SCNNode()
    lightNode.light = SCNLight()
    lightNode.light?.type = .omni
    lightNode.light?.color = UIColor.lightGray
    lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 1000)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

    let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
    ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
    ambientLightNode.light?.type = .ambient
    ambientLightNode.light?.color = UIColor.darkGray
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)

    let geoNode = SCNNode()
    geoNode.name = "model_model"

    let normalsSources = SCNGeometrySource(normals: normalsSCNVector3)
    let verticesSources = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: verticesSCNVector3)
    let texCoordsSources = SCNGeometrySource(textureCoordinates: texCoordCGPoint)
    let indicesElements = SCNGeometryElement(indices: indices, primitiveType: SCNGeometryPrimitiveType.triangles)

    geoNode.geometry = SCNGeometry(sources: [verticesSources, normalsSources, texCoordsSources], elements: [indicesElements])
    geoNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
    geoNode.scale = SCNVector3(x: 50, y: 50, z: 50)

    let material = SCNMaterial()

    material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "grad_ao.png")

    geoNode.geometry?.firstMaterial = material

    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(geoNode)

    return scene
}
```

Model is properly rendered, but applied texture is completely messed up. I have tried with rotated image, also uv coordinates all ok [0..1].

Any ideas? Thank you

[image: Textures are messed up]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to `fix` an issue.

The key is in "texture.png" file.

I just need to flip the image for 180 degrees with:

```
material.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4Translate(SCNMatrix4MakeScale(1, -1, 1), 0, 1, 0)
```